# Google Maps API, driving directions rendering

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to make a call to google maps api to display driving directions based on 2 inputted locations. My skill level is newb.

I am using a notepad to render my html (by pressing ctrl+shift+alt+R), I also tried using xampp to host a local server and then open my html on local (by placing it into htdocs file). While using both of those methods of rendering, each time I input my addresses, the map just blinks and no results are displayed. Is the issue my code or the way I am rendering it? If its the way I am rendering it, could someone please suggest another way I could see/render my html? Thank you very much. Martin

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11"><style type="text/css">.gm-style .gm-style-mtc    
label,.gm-style .gm-style-mtc div{font-weight:400}</style>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<style type="text/css">
  html { height: 100% }
  body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
  #map-canvas { height: 100% ;position:relative;z-index:1}


#panel {
position: fixed; 
bottom: 35px; 
background: rgba(99,99,99,0.7);
width: 97.75%; 
border:3px solid; #FF3D03
border-radius:3px;
z-index: 15; 
font-weight: bold;
font-family: arial;
font-style: normal;
padding: 2px 0px 2px 24px;
}



</style>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?  
key=AIzaSyAzbS2nerrvbdvNlsyQO9cDWFNthdoswRU&sensor=false">
</script>



<div id="map_canvas">


<script type="text/javascript">


var address = new google.maps.LatLng(31.208647, 7.861769);
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;


<!------------------------------------------------------->  
  function initialize() {
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    var mapOptions = {
      center: address,
      zoom: 16,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    }
<!------------------------------------------------------->          
    function calcRoute() {
      var start = document.forms["frame1"]["address0"].value;
      var end = document.forms["frame1"]["address1"].value;
      var request = {
          origin:start,
          destination:end,
          travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
      };
      directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
          directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        }
      });
    }   

<!------------------------------------------------------->          
//  var myTitle = document.createElement('h1');
//  myTitle.style.color = 'red';
//  myTitle.innerHTML = 'menu would go here';
//  var myTextDiv = document.createElement('div');
//  myTextDiv.appendChild(myTitle);

//  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_LEFT].push(myTextDiv);  

//  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
//      position: new google.maps.LatLng(33.6803003, -116.173894),
//      title: "Festival" });

//      marker.setMap(map);}
<!------------------------------------------------------->    

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);



</script>

 </div>

 </head>
  <!-------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
 <body>
 <!-------------------------------------------------------> 
 <!-------------------------------------------------------->

 <div id="panel" style="color:#ffffff; font-size:18px;" >

<form name="frame1" onsubmit="calcRoute();">
<b>Start: </b>
    <input type="text" name="address0">
<b>First Address: </b>
    <input type="text" name="address1">
    <input type="submit" style="visibility: hidden;">
</form>

</div>


    <div id="map-canvas"/>
<!------------------------------------------------------->      
<!------------------------------------------------------->  

  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form submission is reloading the page, destroying the directions response.  Change:

```
<form name="frame1" onsubmit="calcRoute();">
```

To:

```
<form name="frame1" onsubmit="calcRoute();return false;">
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this was exactly it! Is this always the case (page reload) with form submission? So each time I use a form in a div I need that "return false" for it to work?

Comment: Yes. Unless you want the information sent to your server and the server to modify the page based on the submitted information.